# Does the MIT license allow me to make a product that's a front-end for another MIT-license product?

Tags: licensing, mit-license, chrome

I've been struggling with timezones online for a few years now. Because I've had enough of it,  I want to develop a Chrome extension that leverages moment.js so I can paste in a representation of a time and it will return the time in the user's current timezone. So this is basically a GUI front-end for moment.js. I would release this for free on the Chrome web store (and I'm surprised that such a Chrome extension does not exist yet).

Does the MIT license allow this?

Comment: You mind find people unwilling to answer this as it's a legal question. Why not contact the author of moment.js?

Comment: @Liath I've seen other questions about "does X license allow Y?" on this site, so I assumed that people might want to answer it. This is just a question about what the MIT-license allows. and the author of moment.js does not appear to have a contact form on his website.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MIT license is a very permissive license. You can do just about anything with software that is covered by the MIT license except for removing the copyright and license information.

So, yes you can create a GUI front-end for moment.js and you are not even restricted in your choice of license for the front-end.

Comment: Do I need to ask permission to the author before I use it, or can I just download and include it in my plugin with implicit permission?

Comment: @NateKerkhofs: There is no need to ask for permission. The permission was granted implicitly by using the MIT license.